# How to put email to my own mailbox with Java mail API

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am trying to send simple text mail to myself from a servlet using Java Mail API. I wonder how to best approach this in order to avoid daily sent limits meant to restrict sending mail to other people.

How does a mail server receive email? From what information I could find, it is through the SMTP protocol? When the receiver happens to be local, instead of a relay the SMTP server assumes the role of local mail delivery agent. Is that correct? Any problems I could bump into when I connect directly to my SMTP server?

**To avoid any confusion**, I want my servlet to act as an SMTP server, NOT a mail client that connects to one. I want to make a mail server to RECEIVE a message going to my mail box, not relay one to other people.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SMTP is the protocol that a client uses to send an email message to a remote server.

Depending on the server software, there may be ways to send a message to a local server without using SMTP, but (as far as I know) the Java mail framework doesn't know about any of those, it can only use SMTP. So if there are limits on how much you can send, you'll just have to fix those limits directly.

Comment: Please, see the update of my question. I don't want to send on my mail provider side, I want to receive. I will send with Java mail API. There are no limits there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test sending mail from your java application, and you have no development server to connect to, then install a local email server ([hmailserver](http://www.hmailserver.com/) for windows, [postfix](http://www.postfix.org) for *nix).

Configure your email server to only receive email from localhost, and to only deliver to local clients (that way you wont spam the world with your test emails).

Once your happy with your application, you can point it at a production email server. How you connect and the amount of emails you can send will depend on your provider. If you are hosting your own email server you should get professional advice (or do a lot of reasearch) to prevent becoming a spammer, or having a spammer abuse your service (google for open relay).

The postfix site has plenty of good documentation and hmail server has a very good gui.

Comment: Installing local mail server and paying to my mail provider to raise limits that I don't actually need are things that I want to avoid. Very much.